# Lower case text not possible in corner accessory for watchOS widget?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

My watchOS widget view looks like this:

```
struct Corner: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("First")
            .topLineCurved()
            .widgetLabel {
                Text("Second Line")
            }
    }
}

private extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    // Only works in >= watchOS 10, but curves the top line of text in a `accessoryCorner` widget.
    func topLineCurved() -> some View {
        if #available(watchOS 10, *) {
            widgetCurvesContent()
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

However, the text renders like this:

[image]

That is, the text has been converted to upper case. Is it possible to get the text as lower case? Or is the conversion just a fact with these widgets?